# How to make Chrome trust self signed certificates?

Tags: google-chrome, keychain, certificate

I have followed [these instructions](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/) (available from Wayback Machine in case they disappear) to add the certificate of my Asus Router to the keychain but Chrome still refuses to trust it, with the error message "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID". However, Safari accepts it.

I have spent a lot of time on Google looking for answers and there are a lot of articles about this but they seem inconclusive (and many are old).

So how do I make this work?

In case it matters, the router is available both at 192.168.1.1 and router.asus.com (in both cases I use the port 8443).

Bonus: How do I make this certificate work from the outside (both in the case of a FQDN as well as when connecting using the IP-number).

Answer (score 1):

The web page you linked to is old and now incorrect.

Chrome does not use the MacOS keychain any more. Safari does use this so that is why it works.

For more details see this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220660/237).

Comment: That applies to *passwords* (which I was aware of), not certificates. Chrome now offers its own password management but, AFAIK, not its own certificate management. Do you have any other source that can confirm that, and how, Chrome manages certificates independent of the keychain?

Comment: When I click "manage certificates" in Chrome 69, it opens the Mac keychain access app.  So it's still suing the keychain.